# XP Command Line: Use Keyboard To Scroll Through Results?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, scrolling

In a command prompt, how do I scroll up through the results using only the keyboard?

In Linux, I think I could use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Page-Up</kbd>. Is there an equivalent in XP's command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alt+Space, then e, then l. Scroll. Actually, it's just the system menu, as you will see. :D

Then use the arrow keys, of course.

Comment: +1 I was just going to say that, but to be honest, it is easier just to right-click the mouse in the screen, and click scroll.

Comment: Well, the mouse wheel does it, too. So if you don't have a scroll-mouse, that would be the easy way.

Answer (score 2):

Although Abraxas' answer technically does it (I was going to give that as one of my answers too), I don't sense that is what you are really looking for. Normally I would try to summarize this link, but it is fairly involved, so I will just post it. In the end, he actually lets you download the complete script, which should give you the functionality the way I believe you intended.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27080/how-to-scroll-the-command-prompt-window-with-the-keyboard/ (see the download on the last line of the actual article, but before the comments)

Comment: Thanks KCotreau :o) I use AutoHotKey so I will check this out as well!